# How can I PIVOT the values in a column in SQL into new column names and then list other column values under these PIVOT columns?

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

I have a table with 3 columns where the first is the identifier and the two others contains data linked to the value in the first column as follows:

```
ID |   CutOff   | Value
-------------------------------------
01 | 2016-03-31 | AA
01 | 2016-04-30 | AB
01 | 2016-05-31 | AC
02 | 2016-03-31 | BA
02 | 2016-04-30 | BB
02 | 2016-05-31 | BC
03 | 2016-03-31 | FA
03 | 2016-04-30 | FB
03 | 2016-05-31 | FC
```

I need to PIVOT the first column DISTINCT values into column names but maintain the information in the two other columns (CutOff and Value) under the corresponding PIVOTed column. The CutOff dates are the same for all IDs, but the values in the Value column are unique to each ID, and here is the desired result:

```
CutOff     | 01 | 02 | 03 |
---------------------
2016-03-31 | AA | BA | FA
2016-04-30 | AB | BB | FB
2016-05-31 | AC | BC | FC
```

I have Googled and trawled StackExchange for hours without getting there, anyone who could kindly help?

Comment: Tag the dbms used, the answer may be product specific!

Comment: are the IDs variable.. i.e. 04, 05 .. in that case its not very good idea to make table structure in that way.. if its fixed and will never change you can use group by statement etc..

Comment: The IDs are indeed variable, and you are probably right it is not the best way of structuring a table..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select cutoff,
       max(case when id = '01' then value end) as id_01,
       max(case when id = '02' then value end) as id_02,
       max(case when id = '03' then value end) as id_03
from t
group by cutoff
order by cutoff;
```

This is ANSI standard syntax and supported by any database.

Answer (score 0):

If `ID`s are limited you can try this with conditional aggregations:

```
select CutOff,
       max(case when od = '01' then Value end) as [01],
       max(case when od = '02' then Value end) as [02],
       max(case when od = '03' then Value end) as [03]
from tablename
group by CutOff
```

For `SQL Server` you can use native `PIVOT` statement:

```
select CutOff, [01], [02], [03]
from tablename
pivot(max(value) for id in([01], [02], [03])) p
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I finally found a way that works in a similar thread on SE:

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                            QUOTENAME(ID)
                          FROM MyTable
                          WHERE SomeWhereClause
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                          , 1, 1, '');

    SELECT @query =

    'SELECT *
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        o.CutOff,
        p.ID,
        o.Value
      FROM MyTable AS o
      INNER JOIN OtherTableWithID AS p ON o.ID = p.ID
    ) AS t
    PIVOT 
    (
      MAX(Value) 
      FOR Value IN( ' + @cols + ' )' +
    ' ) AS p ; ';

     execute(@query);
```

Comment: dont you need `MAX(Value) FOR ID IN ( ' + @cols + ' )'`